# Некорректное отображение блока "Поделиться" в iOS

Tags: javascript, share, ya-share2

На сайте отображается отлично, в Android тоже.

На iPhone (iOS 9) часть кнопок (VK, Facebook, Google+) не отображается.

Использовал этот код:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//yastatic.net/es5-shims/0.0.2/es5-shims.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//yastatic.net/share2/share.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<div class="ya-share2" data-services="vkontakte,facebook,odnoklassniki,moimir,gplus,linkedin"></div>
```

Comment: Можете дать ссылку на страницу, где воспроизводится проблема?

Comment: @РоманПарадеев Да, конечно. Любая страница сайта http://chili-pepper.ru

Answer (score 1):

Господа, проблема решена
не отображались кнопки только на тех устройствах, где были установлены плагины блокирования рекламы

Comment: Отметьте этот вопрос как решение, пожалуйста.